# jquery validate and jqgrid on same page

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, validation

I am using jqgrid and jquery validate plugin on same page but when I include validate plugin jqgrid is unable to load json data. When I remove the validate plugin it starts working perfectly. I get the follwing error.

> Invalid label
>   Line: 0, Column: 1
>   Source Code:
>   {"page":"1"

Comment: You should append your question with the HTML code and the JavaScript code which can be used to reproduce the problem. Both jqGrid and jQuery.Validate.js can coexist. You should include information about the versions of jQuery, jqGrid and jQuery validate which you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem with jQuery Validate 1.7. I could suggest very easy workaround: to comment the following lines of jQuery.Validate.js:

```
// ajax mode: abort
// usage: $.ajax({ mode: "abort"[, port: "uniqueport"]});
// if mode:"abort" is used, the previous request on that port (port can be undefined) is aborted via XMLHttpRequest.abort() 
;(function($) {
    var ajax = $.ajax;
    var pendingRequests = {};
    $.ajax = function(settings) {
        // create settings for compatibility with ajaxSetup
        settings = $.extend(settings, $.extend({}, $.ajaxSettings, settings));
        var port = settings.port;
        if (settings.mode == "abort") {
            if ( pendingRequests[port] ) {
                pendingRequests[port].abort();
            }
            return (pendingRequests[port] = ajax.apply(this, arguments));
        }
        return ajax.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

If you use the last version 1.8 of jQuery.Validate (you can download it [here](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/1.8.0)) no problem seems exist.

Comment: I think it is back in 1.8.1 jQuery.Validate...!

Comment: @Sai Krishna: I didn't tested that, but it seems to me that the close code exist in the 1.8.1 and 1.9.0 only if you would use some "retro" version of jQuery. Starting with jQuery 1.5 there are [jQuery.ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) method and jQuery Validate [1.8.1](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/1.8.1/jquery.validate.js#L1093) and [1.9.0](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/1.9.0/jquery.validate.js#L1115) use it instead overwriting of `$.ajax`.